# Ubuntu 20.04 Wrong UTC time

Tags: date, timezone

On my Ubuntu server, the time should be UTC+3, but the UTC time zone is 3 hours ahead, and whenever I enter my own time zone, date showing 3+3 6 hours ahead in total. So the UTC timezone is showing incorrectly. How can I solve this problem?

```
               Local time: Tue 2022-12-06 17:55:46 +03
           Universal time: Tue 2022-12-06 14:55:46 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2022-12-06 14:55:46
                Time zone: Europe/Istanbul (+03, +0300)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: Try going into your system clock(in your BIOS) to the correct time.

Comment: I would make sure that your BIOS is set to UTC time.  That is how it is set on my system and then Ubuntu takes care of setting the local time for me.  I have seen this as an issue with dual boot systems also running Windows because Windows by default doesn't use UTC so it has to be set to use a RealTimeIsUniversal change to the registry.  Also, the NTP won't sync properly when your system clock is that far out.

Comment: Is this a physical machine that you can change its BIOS settings? Or is it some cloud VPS? Can you [edit] your question to add the output of `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` also? See also this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/946516/how-to-tell-ubuntu-that-hardware-clock-is-local-time

Comment: I was having this issue on physical Dell server. When I updated the time from the main server's BIOS, the problem was resolved. Thanks.